# CakePHP 3 - saving entities id/created/modified not filled in using sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, cakephp-3.0

I've worked with cake 1 & 2 in the past, first time I'm using cakephp 3.

I tried to do something fairly simple, connect to an sqlite database and create a record.

I wanted the id, created and modified fields to be automatically filled in.
It might be because I'm using sqlite and the table definition is wrong, normally I use mysql or postgres.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id       CHAR (36) PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT      UNIQUE,
    password TEXT      NOT NULL,
    created  INTEGER,
    modified INTEGER
);
```

And what I'm doing to save data in it:

```
$account = new Account([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
]);
TableRegistry::get('Account')->save($account);
```

I've been reading the docs and for id a char(36) should have done the job like it is mentioned here:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created` and `modified` fields are only being populated when using the `Timestamp` behavior, so ensure that you are using it.

Also for CakePHP to be able to properly handle the time fields, you should use a more specific Date/Time type, like `DATETIME`. SQLite will internally treat these as numerical columns nonetheless, but CakePHP needs these types in order to be able to map the values to the proper database type classes.

As for your `id` column, remove the whitespace between `CHAR` and `(36)`, SQLite will return the type as defined, ie with the whitespace, `CHAR (36)`, and CakePHP is looking for `CHAR(36)`, without whitespace.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../blob/3.1.5/src/Database/Schema/SqliteSchema.php#L47](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/Database/Schema/SqliteSchema.php#L47)**

See also

- **https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html**

Comment: Was indeed the case, the table create sql was generated using a GUI tool,  the timestamps started to work as well as soon as I added the behavior and used timestamp as type.

Comment: I had the same problem using CakePHP 3.4. I solved using this in my Model/Table:

 public function initialize(array $config)
  {
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
  }
More informations here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html